# If a user of my app OAuth-authenticates their Google account… can we provide a UI to switch accounts?

Tags: oauth, google-contacts-api

1. User comes to Widgets.Example.com.
2. We prompt them, “Want to import you Google contacts?”
3. They do, using OAuth 3.0… with their business Google account.
4. “Oops. Wrong set of contacts,” thinks the user, upon seeing the result at Widgets.Example.com. They wanted their personal contacts, instead.
5. Here, we would like to provide a mechanism that allows them to switch accounts.

I currently don’t believe that is possible. Is it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Apparently, you cannot.

(Other valid answers would be accepted as they come in. Gotta bring up my accept rate.)